# Scroll to next item in list using Next key from softkeyboard

Tags: android, listview

I have the following issue:

I have a listview with custom rows, and on each row there are several edit texts (one or two).
I want to be able to scroll to next element every time I touch the next button from the soft keyboard.
I have implemented the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if (displayFlag == GuiConstants.GUI_QUICK_DISPLAY) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION: {
                    scrollToNext();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private void scrollToNext() {
    int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    if (currentPosition == listView.getCount() - 1)
        return;
    listView.setSelection(currentPosition + 1);

}
```

The problem is that the list scrolls and works great until a row has to be created (it is not yet visible). At this point the `Next` button is replaced by `Done` button.

**Does anybody have any idea what can I do?**
Or maybe can somebody point a tutorial where I can find more about this issue?

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use custom  EditText  here is the code that might help you

```
EditText test = new EditText(context){


                            @Override
                            public void onEditorAction(int actionCode) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onEditorAction(actionCode);

                                if(actionCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){

                                } 
                            }
                        };
```

Comment: The only problem is that the callback for onEditorAction is never called when the view is behind softkeyboard (or at least on the last position before the list has to scroll down). Any idea why is that happening?